# ActivityNotFoundException - Send Intent between two apps

Tags: android

I am trying to send an intent from the MainActivity of App A to the MainActivity of App B and then bring the App B to the front but when starting the App A I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=com.example.app.MainActivity
>   pkg=com.example.app (has extras) }

First, I am starting the App B and then the App A.

How can I send an intent from the MainActivity of app A to the MainActivity of app B and then bringing the app B to the front ?

App A MainActivity:

```
package com.mysender;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String pdfString = "Hello World";

        final Intent intent= new Intent("com.example.app.MainActivity");
        intent.setPackage("com.example.app");
        intent.putExtra("path", pdfString);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

App A Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mysender">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App B MainActivity:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    //private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(data!=null){
            String myString = data.getString("Id");
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data Received from External App: " ,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

}
```

App B Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Error:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=com.example.app.MainActivity
>   pkg=com.example.app (has extras) }

```
    final Intent intent= new Intent("com.example.app.MainActivity");
    intent.setPackage("com.example.app");
    intent.putExtra("path", pdfString);
    startActivity(intent);
```

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   explicit activity class
>   {com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}; have you declared this
>   activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
final Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app", "com.example.app.MainActivity"));
intent.putExtra("path", pdfString);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit:**

I have changed my manifest B to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="com.mysender.Data"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the MainActivity of App A to:

package com.mysender;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String pdfString = "Hello World";


    final Intent intent= new Intent("com.example.app.MainActivity");
    intent.setPackage("com.example.app");
    intent.setAction("com.mysender.Data");
    intent.putExtra("path", pdfString);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

but I am still getting the error:

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity
>   found to handle Intent { act=com.mysender.Data pkg=com.example.app
>   (has extras) }

Comment: I think manifest B should use `.MainActivity`, and your last code block here shouldn't prefix the MainActivity with a package

Comment: With regards to your first error, you do not have any activity set up with an `<intent-filter>` that responds to that action string.

Comment: @cricket_007: would you take a look at my edited question part?

Comment: In the new error... `act=com.mysender.Data`. This is not an intent filter in your manifest